How can I restrict an interface type based on a generic parameter?
Given:
interface Foo<T> {
  data: T[] | SomeWrapper<T>
}

I want to change this so that data can only be an array if T = string. So if this syntax worked, I'd do
interface Foo<T> {
  data: T === typeof(string) 
          ? T[] | SomeWrapper<T> 
          : SomeWrapper<T>
}

I feel like there's some solution with never here, but not sure how to construct it...

Are you just looking for conditional types like this?   If so I'll write it up as an answer, if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yeah I think that's the answer to this question; my problem is that trying this with my more complex typings, calling Foo<["blue", "red", "green"]> Is yielding data: "blue"[] | "green"[] | "red"[], rather than a normal array signature I'd expect (either string[] or ("red" | "blue" | "green")[]), but this is far enough removed from the question I asked here, so I may ask again with a minimal example. Thanks though :)

I see you already accepted someone else's answer, so, uh... good luck!

you can use conditional types for this.
interface Foo<T> {
  data: T extends string ? SomeWrapper<T>[] : SomeWrapper<T>
}

The syntax is similar as for ternary expressions and lets you define types according to some logic around what a given type extends. So a basic and clear example would be
type IsString<T> = T extends string ? true : false

Given the above type, IsString<"hi"> has type true and IsString<5> has type false.
